# Optparse in python: how to use integers inside file.dat when file.dat was used as an argument in command line

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, parsing, optparse

I have a script that has several functionalities that are accessed through the command line via optparse. I recently changed this part of the code (full updated function of the code at end):

```
parser.add_option('-d','--distance',dest='distance',nargs=2,type='int',
                     help='require a distance calculation on the specified couple of atoms')
```

I changed type='int' to type='str' so I could use the code as: `python code.py -d 999 list.dat file.arc`

Unfortunately this just passes the filename 'list.dat' but does not pass the integers inside of list.dat which is what I want. How can I pass the contents of list.dat to argparse and not just the filename 'list.dat'?

The full parser function is below. Thank you.

```
def parsecmd():
    description="Calculate distances, angles, torsions and quota in periodic or\
 non-periodic molecular structures.\n\
See documentation for further information."
    usage="usage: %prog [options] input_file"
    #updtate this when new formats are added

    list_of_formats="XYZ/XMOL, TINKER XYZ/ARC"
    #parse command line
    parser=OP(version='%prog 1.1',description=description,usage=usage)

    parser.add_option('-c','--credits',dest='credits',action='store_true',
                     default=False,help='display credits')
    parser.add_option('-f','--format',dest='fformat', default="arc",
                      help='specify the format of the input structure, [default: %default]')
    parser.add_option('-e','--filedata',dest='filedata',nargs=1,
                      help='specify that input file is setup file')
    parser.add_option('-d','--distance',dest='distance',nargs=2,type='str',
                     help='require a distance calculation on the specified couple of atoms')
    parser.add_option('-a','--angle',dest='angle',nargs=3,type='int',
                     help='require angle calculation on the specified three atoms')
    parser.add_option('-i','--dih',dest='dih',nargs=4,type='int',
                     help='dihedral angle four atoms')
    parser.add_option('-t','--torsion',dest='torsion',nargs=5,type='int',
                     help='require torsions calculation on the specified four atoms and periodicity (i.e. 360 deg)')
    parser.add_option('-u','--unitcell',dest='periodicity',nargs=6,type='float',
                     help='define periodic unit cell (a,b,c in angstrom; alpha,beta,gamma in degrees)')
    parser.add_option('-l','--listformats',dest='listformats',action='store_true',
                     default=False, help='list the available formats')
    (options, args) = parser.parse_args(argv[1:])
```

Comment: This looks like `optparse` code, not `argparse`.  I don't see where or how it's supposed to read a file.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#fromfile-prefix-chars

Comment: You’re totally right — this is optparse. It’s passing the file name in as an argument. I just don’t know the proper way to read it since args has several arguments in it. The arguments it prints if I do print (args) gives me ([999,list.dat]) .Thank you for taking your time to help me with this.  

Edit: added more information

Comment: `argparse` does implement a deal where you mark a string with a special character like '@', and it reads that file and splices the strings into the commandline (before parsing).  Otherwise, you just have to accept a list of strings, and decide for yourself what to do with strings that look like file names.

Comment: I see. I thought options was a dict but it isn't. How would one access what it is printing out individually? when I `print (option)` it returns `(<Values at 0x10fc0b5f0: {'distance': ('229', 'list_of_sulfurs.dat'), 'listformats': False, 'dih': None, 'periodicity': None, 'credits': False, 'angle': None, 'filedata': None, 'fformat': 'arc', 'torsion': None}>, 'options0')` I want to use and open 'list_of_sulfurs.dat' but using `print (option[2]) does not work (thank you for your patience)

Comment: `option.distance` should be the tuple `('229', 'list_of_sulfurs.dat')`.  So `int(option.distance[0]` would be a number, and `option.distance[1]` the name of a file, which you can `open` and `read`.  You could use `vars(option)` as a dictionary if you prefer.

Comment: Okay, I used that. I added to my main loop ` if options.distance:`
        `sulfurs = options.distance[1]`
        `with open(sulfurs) as fp:`
            `line = fp.read().split('\n')`
            `print(tasklist,'tasklist')`   -Edit: Formatting issues- @hpaulj could you make the option.distance[1] an answer so I can make it the official answer please? Thank you so much for your help!